# React Native iOS: Duplicate Symbols i.e. `duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule`

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

So I've got the dreaded how many ever duplicate symbols for unknown reasons.

**Example**

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule
```

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule in:
    /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/clustr/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
    /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/clustr/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
ld: 284 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

[image]

I'm a tad confused as to why though here's my library list

[image]

My Podfile is currently like this as I investigate the reason behind duplicate symbols

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'clustr' do

#    # Flexbox Layout Manager Used By React Natve
   pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
#
#    # React Native
    pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
#    # Comment out any unneeded subspecs to reduce bundle size.
    'Core',
#    'DevSupport',
#    'RCTActionSheet',
#    'RCTAnimation',
#    'RCTBlob',
#    'RCTCameraRoll',
##    'RCTGeolocation',
##    'RCTImage',
##    'RCTNetwork',
#    'RCTPushNotification',
##    'RCTSettings',
#    'RCTTest',
##    'RCTText',
##    'RCTVibration',
##    'RCTWebSocket',
##    'RCTLinkingIOS'
    ]

    # OneSignal
    # pod 'OneSignal', '~> 1.13.3'

    # Mapbox
    pod 'react-native-mapbox-gl', :path => '../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'

    pod 'Stripe', '~> 10.1.0'

    inherit! :search_paths
end

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'clustr' do

#    # Flexbox Layout Manager Used By React Natve
   pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
#
#    # React Native
    pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
#    # Comment out any unneeded subspecs to reduce bundle size.
    'Core',
#    'DevSupport',
#    'RCTActionSheet',
#    'RCTAnimation',
#    'RCTBlob',
#    'RCTCameraRoll',
##    'RCTGeolocation',
##    'RCTImage',
##    'RCTNetwork',
#    'RCTPushNotification',
##    'RCTSettings',
#    'RCTTest',
##    'RCTText',
##    'RCTVibration',
##    'RCTWebSocket',
##    'RCTLinkingIOS'
    ]

    # OneSignal
    # pod 'OneSignal', '~> 1.13.3'

    # Mapbox
    pod 'react-native-mapbox-gl', :path => '../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'

    pod 'Stripe', '~> 10.1.0'

    inherit! :search_paths
end
```

Comment: Because you have react-native both in libraries and in pods. If you go cocoapods way, you have to remove React and everyhting you put into its subspecs from Libraries section. I advise you against that, I would use the non-pods approach when installing libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SergeSeredenko So would you advise not using `CocoaPods` at all? I know there were some difficulties in installing MapBox and Stripe the manual approach that's all.

And if so, how do I go about starting the xcode project again in this case? Delete the folder and run `react-native-git-upgrade`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just remove stuff from your Podfile and run `pod install` again (if you didn't change your configs much for React in pods). You can use cocoapods, just those which depend on pod React are problematic because they force you to move react-native to pods. For example, OneSignal and Stripe should be fine.

Comment: Okay thanks @SergeSeredenko with my current config, simulators run fine, archive does not with the error

`ld: '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture armv7
clang: ```

Comment: I do not know about iOS much, so cannot really help. Try to search the web or ask a separate question here.

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error, removing React from the Pods targets fixes the issue.

It is caused by the conflict between CocoaPods adding React and how React gets added to the libraries section usually when linking.